# Add a full stop between user's first and last names

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where column A contains a list of employee
first and last names. I want column B to shows the users first and last names but with a "." in between.

Column A currently shows
dave smith

Column B needs to show
dave.smith

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1)&"."&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

or

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",".")
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose A1 has `dave smith`. In B1, you could place `=FIND(" ",A1)` which would find the first space.

Then in C1, you could place `=REPLACE(A1,B1,1,".")` which would replace the first space with a period.

It's not very sturdy, and would not work if there were only one name or if the first name had two words (like "Bobby Sue Klinefelter").